# Word VSTO Add-In : Writing to the Word Status Bar

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, vsto

For my Word add-in project I'd very much like to add some "dynamic statistics" to the Word status bar, similar to the word count.

The only way to do this that I've found is basically :

```
Application.StatusBar = "The message";
```

However this simply replaces the entire status bar with my string.

Googling the problem only yielded this 2011 thread, which tells me that my experience is basically how things were back in 2011 :

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/1471ed7c-ecd4-463d-ac52-4ff248abae0c/how-to-add-information-in-status-bar-in-word-and-excel

I'm wondering if anything has changed in that department, considering this is 2018 and I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and Office Pro 2016.

Answer (score 0):

From that very link I see this, from the venerable Cindy Meister:

> Add to that the fact that the property is no longer officially supported from Word 2007 onwards (ony [sic] for reasons of backwards compatibility)...

Also, from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._application.statusbar.aspx):

> **_Application.StatusBar property**
>
> **Office 2013 and later**
>
> Displays the specified text in the status bar.
>
> Namespace:  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
>
> Assembly:  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word (in Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll)
>
> **Syntax**
>
> string StatusBar { set; }

Looks the same to me. It hasn't changed.

Comment: So there isn't some other mechanism that may have been built into newer versions of Word to access the status bar ? It seems odd that this would be missing.

Comment: It's consistent with the rest of Word, in the way that it's a user-focused application first, and an API second. E.g. in a similar way, you can group actions into a custom record for Undo, but you can't view or modify the Undo stack at all. This kind of thing is fairly common.